# remove untracked file but not delete it from hard disk

Tags: git, git-clean

In my branch A, I created a new directory `myDir`. I commited all changes on that branch by `git add .` and commit. I don't see any untracked file or directory.

Then I switch to branch B, I see untracked file `myDir`.

How can I remove `myDir` from branch B but still have it when switch to branch A ? I mean I don't want to really delete `myDir` from hard disk and I don't want to see untracked file `myDir` either on branches (other than branch A) .

I know there is `git clean` command, but it deletes files from hard disk, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real problem removing `myDir` from your disk, when you will switch back to branch **A**, `myDir` will appear again.

So you can safely use `git clean` (in this case, since you already committed `myDir` on another branch).

Comment: Thanks, could you please clarify to me that does `git clean` delete file from hard disk or not? If it does deletion from hard disk how could git keep it when switching back to branch A?

Comment: @Leem.fin Each commit is a hash and contains info. It describes the tree of your project with its files and their content. Even when your directory `myDir` will be deleted, git has written everything it needs to recreate it.

Comment: To simplify a little: when you `git commit`, a copy of each file is put under your `.git` directory, so after that you cannot lose the file anymore (unless you remove your `.git` directory)

Comment: @RomainValeri I understand that, each commit is a hash containing info, but if the hash referenced/described file is permanentely deleted from hard disk, how can git recover it? That's my main question here.  I don't understand if `git clean` delete file from hard disk, how can switching to branch A still have the file. Unless `git clean` doesn't really delete file from hard disk.

Comment: @Leem.fin Why would the hash itself be deleted? We're talking about deleting the directory. The hash is inside `.git`, your directory isn't.

Comment: @ChrisMaes so, in short, you mean git copy real physical files to `.git`. Right? If so, it makes sense to me now. That's the answer I need. Thanks.

Comment: @RomainValeri I was saying the hash referenced file, not the hash. My understanding is the hash is referencing a file in hard disk, like pointer. If I understand wrongly, let me know.

Comment: @Leem.fin "so, in short, you mean git copy real physical files to `.git`. Right?" No, it creates a hash from the whole tree plus metadata, and stores that hash inside `.git`. But the files themselves are not stored as such in `.git`. Chris answer is fine :-)

Comment: @RomainValeri If I ask in another way: Does the hash act like a pointer/reference pointing/refering to the the physical file on hard disk?

Comment: @Leem.fin No. It's an encrypted version of the data itself, it doesn't point to the real file, it incorporates its contents in a short form, which will need to be unhashed to be used.

Comment: @RomainValeri so, it is a "copy" because you said it is an encrypted version of the data under `.git`. Otherwise, how can a file permanately deleted from hard disk be available again in another branch. There must be a sort of "copy", doesn't matter encrypted version or whatever version "copy" is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199945/discussion-between-romainvaleri-and-leem-fin).